# Внешнее и внутреннее содержание

Tags: грамотная-речь

Существует выражение "внутреннее содержание", когда говорится о внутреннем мире человека. Интересно, относится ли оно к смысловой избыточности, ведь содержание - это априори внутренняя составляющая? Или это устойчивое выражение, так как если сказать только "содержание", будет не совсем понятен смысл?
В то же время встречается сочетание "внешнее и внутреннее содержание". Логически понятно, что "внешнее" здесь в значении "форма". Возможно ли тогда такое выражение?

Answer (score 2):

Действительно, даже в речи лингвистов находит употребление риторический штамп "*внутреннее и внешнее содержание*" (в разной последовательности). Но это не более чем попытка объединительного упрощения (внутреннее *содержание* + внешняя *форма*, облик или внешние признаки, атрибуты и т. п. чего-либо). Если в качестве примера взять заголовок выложенной [здесь](https://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/vnutrennee-i-vneshnee-soderzhanie-yazykovogo-znaka/viewer) статьи "*Внутреннее и внешнее содержание языкового знака*", то из текста выясняется, что речь идет о внешней "форме" и о противопоставлении объективного (внутреннего) содержания субъективно воспринимаемому (внешнему). Буквальная трактовка словосочетания "*внешнее содержание*" в бытовом понимании ведет к противоречию, которое вы и отметили в вопросе. Если только в какой-нибудь узкой области знания нет одноименного термина, формулировку "*внутреннее и внешнее содержание*" я бы трактовал как *канцеляризм* (это попадается и в циркулярах об организации учебного процесса в вузах), во всяком случае, избегал бы его употребления в повседневной речи.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, тогда насколько может быть благозвучна фраза "...и внутреннее содержание волновало его гораздо больше, чем внешнее"? Речь идет о внутреннем мире человека. "Внешнее" здесь выступает по задумке прилагательным, но на слух может восприниматься и как существительное, поэтому противоречие, о котором идет речь, будто немного смягчается. Как вы думаете?..

Comment: Здесь правильнее обойтись словом "внешность" или "видимость" (что по контексту ближе). Даже если "внешнее" задумывалось как существительное, воспринимается это слово как однородное с первым прилагательным определение.